# How to install native Storage

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

Can anyone explain How to install **nativeStorage** and Import it with example

Because I have an error when running my app `Error storing item cordova_not_available`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get rid of your error message `cordova_not_available` you can try these steps:

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

and use `ionic cordova run browser` instead of `ionic serve`.

To install the Ionic Native Storage module you can use the official documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Let me know if this fixed your problem already or if you need more instructions.

Comment: This is solved my problem I don't need more instructions. ^_^